# select duplicate columns by inner join

Tags: sql, sql-server

Original:

(C1,    C2, C3)

(  A,   1,  R0)

(  A,   1,  R1)

( A,    2,  R0)

( A,    3,  R0)

( A,    3,  R1)

( A,    4,  R0)

( A ,5,     R0)

 ( B,   1   ,R0)

Result:

(C1,    C2, C3)

 ( A,   1    ,R0)

 ( A,   1    ,R1) 

 ( A,   3   ,R0) 

 ( A,   3   ,R1)

Trying to show a table that people can compare data with same 'C2' but different 'C3'

I tried inner join with its own like this

```
select * from myTable a  inner join myTable b on a.C2 = b.C2 and b.C3 = 'R1' and b.C1 = 'A' and  a.C1 = 'A'
```

How to set this query shorter?

Comment: Why has the result a `C1` value of `B`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If row `B, 1 ,R0` is typo in your output, then you can use window function [count()](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx) to get desired output:

```
with cte as (
    select *, count(*) over(partition by C1, C2) as cnt
    from Table1
)
select C1, C2, C3
from cte
where cnt > 1
```

**<kbd>[sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a4042/4)</kbd>**

Comment: Thanks for answering. It works pretty well. If insert a new row (A,1,R2) and I only want to show rows with R1 and R2 where should i set the conditions?

Comment: If I understand your task, you can filter it inside the cte, like 'from Table1 where C3 in ('R1', 'R2')'

Answer (score 0):

You can group & count C2 and select when the count is greater than 1
single c2's (like A,2,R0 ) doesn't appear
a,1,RO and a,1,r1 shown like your results